# R Comparing row values in one column given that 3 conditions are fulfilled

Tags: r, loops, comparison, row

Although I have searched a lot on stackoverflow I could not find an answer for my problem. It is quite tricky because I want only to compare row values in one column given that 3 conditions are fulfilled.
I want to compare 2 row values within the same column (Result) if and only if they they are in the same treatment, group and period. My goal is then to evaluate whether player 1 and player 2 scored the same result (1 = if yes, 0= if no). In total, I have five columns: Treatment; Player; Group; Result; Period. 
Below the table.

```
    df
T   Player    Group      Result  Period    Same Result
1     1         6          20      1          1
1     2         6          20      1          1
1     1         5          20      1          0
1     2         1          20      1          1
1     1         1          20      1          1
1     2         2          20      1          1
1     1         2          20      1          1
1     2         4          120     1          1
1     1         3          20      1          1
1     2         3          20      1          1
1     1         4          120     1          1
1     2         5          120     1          0

2     1         2          20      1          1
2     2         1          120     1          1
2     1         4          20      1          0
2     2         5          20      1          1
2     1         6          20      1          1
2     2         2          20      1          1
2     1         3          20      1          1 
2     2         3          20      1          1
2     1         1          120     1          1
2     2         6          20      1          1
2     1         5          20      1          1
2     2         4          120     1          0
```

Any ideas? Help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse` you can do the following. First, `group_by` your 3 columns of interest: treatment, group, and period. Then, use `n_distinct` for each group to see if only 1 unique result for that group.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(T, Group, Period) %>%
  mutate(Same_Result_2 = +(n_distinct(Result) == 1))
```

Alternative with `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, Same_Result_3 := if(uniqueN(Result)==1) 1 else 0, by=.(T, Group, Period)]
```

**Output**

`Same_Result_1` is value provided in example. `Same_Result_2` is determined by above `tidyverse` code.

```
# A tibble: 24 x 7
# Groups:   T, Group, Period [12]
       T Player Group Result Period Same_Result_1 Same_Result_2
   <int>  <int> <int>  <int>  <int>         <int>         <int>
 1     1      1     6     20      1             1             1
 2     1      2     6     20      1             1             1
 3     1      1     5     20      1             0             0
 4     1      2     1     20      1             1             1
 5     1      1     1     20      1             1             1
 6     1      2     2     20      1             1             1
 7     1      1     2     20      1             1             1
 8     1      2     4    120      1             1             1
 9     1      1     3     20      1             1             1
10     1      2     3     20      1             1             1
11     1      1     4    120      1             1             1
12     1      2     5    120      1             0             0
13     2      1     2     20      1             1             1
14     2      2     1    120      1             1             1
15     2      1     4     20      1             0             0
16     2      2     5     20      1             1             1
17     2      1     6     20      1             1             1
18     2      2     2     20      1             1             1
19     2      1     3     20      1             1             1
20     2      2     3     20      1             1             1
21     2      1     1    120      1             1             1
22     2      2     6     20      1             1             1
23     2      1     5     20      1             1             1
24     2      2     4    120      1             0             0
```

Comment: Dear Ben, Thank you very much for your help, could not have come up with this solution without you. Works like clockwork!